# How can i display tooltip at the top of each vertical bar

Tags: d3.js

I have tried writing couple of equations for the same but unabe to get it aligned well. I need to display tooltip at the top of each bar.
[Here is fiddle of the same](https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/9/)

I am using mouseover events to display tooltips

```
sets.append("rect")
                    .attr("class","global")
                    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()/2)
                    .attr('y', function(d) {
                        return yScale((d.global/total)*100);
                    })
                    .attr("height", function(d){
                        return h - yScale((d.global/total)*100);
                    })
                    .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
                    return color(d.global);
                    }) 
                    .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
                        var xPos = xScale.rangeBand()*i;
                        //console.log(xScale(i)); 6 190 282
                        console.log(xScale.rangeBand()*i);
                        var yPos = yScale((d.global / total) * 100);

                        d3.select('#hor_tooltip')
                            .style('left', xPos + 'px')
                            .style('top', yPos + 'px')
                            .style('display', 'block')
                            .html(d.global);
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function() {
                        d3.select('#hor_tooltip').style('display', 'none');
                    })
                    .append("text")
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return commaFormat((d.global/total)*100);
                    })
                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("font-size", "11px")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use d3.event inside the mouseover event handler. You can use the x,y coordinates of the event or request the bounding box of the evnet target element.
The following code should help but you still need to adjust for the height of the tootip itself:

```
 var px = d3.event.pageX;
 var py = d3.event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Comment: I have worked on the same and got this; https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/10/  was this what you were hinting at?

Comment: Yes, I just thought you wanted the toottip above the bars (on top).

Comment: what does d3.event.pagex position with respect to? mouse position?

Comment: Yes, mouse X coordinate relative to whole document.

Comment: hey it works well with chrom but in IE a blck box is appearing first then the actual tooltip styling. Any guess why?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: i fixed it; background was having color attributes in two places. :)

Answer (score -2):

You could also try foxTooltip.js. It has an option to always position on a specific side of an element. 
https://github.com/MichaelRFox/foxToolTip.js